# Using $_SERVER to get the webroot

Tags: php, apache, cakephp

I am using following code in the cakephp project in bootstrap to define constants like webroot path. Is it right

```
$_ROOTPATH  = strtolower('http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$URLPART    = explode('cake',$_ROOTPATH);

define('ROOTPATH',$URLPART[0].'cake/');
define('RESOURCEBASEPATH',$URLPART[0].'resources/');
define('DOCUMENTROOTPATH',substr($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'],0,-9));
```

1. ROOTPATH in place of $this->webroot .
2. DOCUMENTROOTPATH pointing to actual to piont to the actual path as in **`/var/www/`**

What do you say about this.  Any note/suggestion is welcome.

Comment: `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` would be the "official" document root as set in the httpd.cond

Comment: @MarcB i am refering to the cakephp webroot which is something like /apachewebroot/path/to/cake/app/webroot/

Comment: Although CakePHP works when [sitting under the Apache webroot](http://book.cakephp.org/view/913/Development), it is also possible to configure the [Apache webroot to be `app/webroot`](http://book.cakephp.org/view/914/Production). In the latter case, `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` and `WWW_ROOT` are the same directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding file paths, have you looked at the existing [core constants](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1141/Core-Definition-Constants)? You will probably find most of the file path constants you need are already defined there.

For example, your `DOCUMENTROOTPATH` is exactly the same as (I believe) the `WWW_ROOT` constant.

As for URLs, CakePHP's `Router::url()` takes care of handling all URLs in a consistent manner (eg. URLs output by `Controller::redirect()`, `FormHelper`, `HtmlHelper`, etc.)

You can also call `Router::url()` statically wherever you need to create URLs:

```
echo Router::url('/some/random/path');
// output: http://www.example.com/path/to/cake/some/random/path
echo Router::url(array('controller' => 'abc', 'action' => 'xyz'));
// output: http://www.example.com/path/to/cake/abc/xyz
```

Unless I am missing something, I would just use the above instead of littering your application with the likes of `ROOTPATH` and `RESOURCEBASEPATH`. For example the following approaches are equivalent:

```
$this->redirect(ROOTPATH . 'some/place'); // your way
// takes you to: http://www.example.com/path/to/cake/some/place
$this->redirect('/some/place'); // cake way
// takes you to: http://www.example.com/path/to/cake/some/place

echo $this->Html->image(RESOURCEBASEPATH . 'some/image.jpg'); // your way
// outputs: <img src="http://www.example.com/path/to/cake/resources/some/image.jpg" />
echo $this->Html->image('some/image.jpg'); // cake way
// outputs: <img src="http://www.example.com/path/to/cake/img/some/image.jpg" />
echo $this->Html->image('../resources/some/image.jpg'); // cake way
// outputs: <img src="http://www.example.com/path/to/cake/resources/some/image.jpg" />
```

Comment: Thanks for www_root will look into it as for as images are considered  they are not in cake webroot but in a  folder outside of cake (sub-directory). Also using cake php helpsr for other than form(model validation) leads to a performance hit

Comment: > "leads to a performance hit" - Yes, but so does using a framework. Caching can be used to minimize the performance hit (opcode caching, result caching, view caching, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Why not use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`

Comment: i am refering to the cakephp webroot which is something like /apachewebroot/path/to/cake/app/webroot/

Answer (score 1):

you don't need no variable to get a webroot. 
it is always just `/`. Very handy.

Comment: i am refering to the cakephp webroot which is something like /apachewebroot/path/to/cake/app/webroot/

Answer (score 0):

I am using this (assuming that I am in the right folder with the file that I am writing this code in):

```
$path = realpath(dirname(__FILE__)).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty old post, but in case anyone wants to know. It is $this->webroot which gives you the webroot of the application. this is available in the controller & the views too.